# How to test a ReactJs component that changes its state after a certain time

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

[Link to playground with my code](https://repl.it/repls/ScientificAmusedPyramid#src/App.test.js)

I have a simple component:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("text1");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setText("text2");
    }, 5000);
  });

  return (
    <div>{text}</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It immediately renders "text1". And after 5 seconds it renders "text2". I need to test this behavior.

Here is my test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

jest.useFakeTimers();

test('has text1 on start, text2 in 5 seconds', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);

  expect(getByText('text1')).toBeInTheDocument();

  jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);

  expect(getByText('text2')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I get warning: "An update to null inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)".

[image]

How to avoid this warning? I tried to wrap in act() everything, it doesn't help.

Here is a playground with this example (to run test, type "npm t" in console):
https://repl.it/repls/ScientificAmusedPyramid#src/App.test.js

Comment: have you tried `import { App }  from './App'.` or how are you exporting `App`?

Comment: please look at https://repl.it/repls/ScientificAmusedPyramid#src/App.test.js : I use "import App from './App';" (because App.js has default export)

Comment: can I run tests in your link?

Comment: the test passes for me?

Comment: yes, sure. type "npm t" in the console (right bottom window). you will see the warning

Comment: try my answer now Lldar

Comment: let me know if this worked for you lldar? if not, we can try and work something else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`act(() => jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000))`

I tried this and it worked for me, I didn't see any warnings

`import { act } from 'react-testing-library'`

reference: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually I tried this in my real application and it didn't work. Thats why I didn't check it in the playground. But when you tell me that this works in playground I found the cause of the error. In my real app I have many tests. And for some reason to avoid this warning I had to add "act(() => jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000))" and I had to add "act(() => jest.runAllTimers())" after each test. Then everything is ok.